# Bootcamp puts content in Macintosh Harddrive

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, bootcamp

I am using Paragon HFS+ for reading my Macintosh hard drive in windows but when I open my Macintosh hard drive I saw lot of window's garbage that I never kept inside of it. Can I delete .exe files and EULA stuff? How to stop windows from keeping it again automatically to Macintosh drive?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly these files belong to the VisualC++ redistributable. When the installer runs it extracts these files to the root of a drive and then installs to the correct folder. Once the install is complete, these files can just be deleted.

This isn't really anything to do with Boot Camp.